# docker stuck on django runserver

Tags: python, django, docker, ubuntu, virtualbox

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim
ENV root=/test
ENV django=$root/test
COPY ./code $root
WORKDIR $django
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
CMD ["python3",  "manage.py", "runserver", "--noreload"]
```

without --noreload it will stuck on

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
```

FYI, "docker run hello-world" is working fine.

FYI, running ubuntu on virtualbox on windows 10 home(as dev env)

**UPDATE:**
I have changed the base image to

> FROM python:3.6

and it works, but the question is still there **why it is not working with slim?**

Comment: You should be running it using `uwsgi` or something similar inside the container. `runserver` command is only for local development

Answer (score 0):

What is your DEBUG value in settings? Can you change to False.

It's not related to docker image slip or any other image per say. Django is looking for hot-reload, whenever there is change in code, used for development purpose. But inside Docker it's not required as, I believe, you aren't changing your code.

Also use a wsgi/u for deployments - Gunicorn, uvicorn etc.